# Change num_classes hyperparameter for SageMaker Incremental training

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

I am performing incremental training on a model I already trained in SageMaker. I want to add data to the existing classes as well as create new classes. The first model had 4 classes (num_classes = 4) but I want to keep those classes as well as add 3 additional classes.

The documentation says that the num_classes hyperparameter must be the same when doing incremental training. But if that is the case, that means I cannot add classes to my existing model, I would have to start from scratch each time I wanted to change the number of classes. Is this accurate? Or is there a way to update an existing model and change the number of classes it is trained on?

Here is the example notebook I am using for the incremental training job:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-incremental-training-highlevel.ipynb

[See num_classes parameter here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc6Uq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For incremental training with the SageMaker built-in Image Classification algorithm, the input hyperparameters of both the new model and the pre-trained model must have the same settings for the `num_layers`, `image_shape` and `num_classes` input parameters. Because these parameters define the network architecture.

Typically, for newly added classes you would create a new dataset with old and new classes and update the model weights on the new dataset. As far as I know, this is not possible with SageMaker Image Classification algorithm.

Comment: That is what I have found as well. I was hoping there was some workaround. I am doing transfer-learning, and SageMaker uses the ResNet model for Image Classification. Seeing as that the ResNet model is based off ImageNet with around 1000 classes, anytime we do transfer learning we are essentially changing the num_classes, so in theory we should be able to change the num_classes when doing incremental as well.